# Нужно ли тире перед "попросту невежливо"?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Тире здесь может стоять только факультативно? Т. к. подразумевается, что "ЭТО невежливо"?

> Я прекрасно понимаю, что совать нос в его личные дела (–) попросту невежливо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно сказать и так – факультативно. Скорее, постановка тире зависит от акцентов, интонации.

В данном случае я бы его поставил, так как предложение не очень короткое, а также будет понятно, к чему относится слово ***попросту***.

> 5. При наличии паузы между главными членами предложения **тире** ставится между подлежащим, выраженным неопределенной формой глагола, и сказуемым, выраженным предикативным наречием на **-о** (категорией состояния): *Уступить — позорно* (Тендр.); *Это очень **несносно — переезжать*** (Гонч.); *Это **ужасно — струсить** в последний момент; Это чертовски **весело — кататься** на лодке* [ср. без паузы: ***Кататься** на лодке **весело***; ***Судить** человека в немилости очень **легко*** (Л. Т.)].

Источник: [**Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92) (Розенталь).

Comment: Уважаемый Александр! Но у того же Розенталя говорится, что тире не ставится, если между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит союз, наречие, вводное слово и т.д. Здесь  стоит наречие "попросту", поэтому тире не ставится

Comment: @виктор1799 Да, Виктор, я это знаю и думал об этом. Но, во-первых, это примечание дается в 1-м пункте, где говорится о подлежащем и сказуемом, выраженными **существительными**, во-вторых,  там написано "**обычно** не ставится", а в третьих, интонационное тире никто не отменял.

Comment: Насчет интонационного тире я на Вашей стороне

Answer (score 2):

Я полагаю, тире в вашем случае *необходимо*, потому что без него возникает двусмысленность. Сравните:

**1. Я прекрасно понимаю, что совать нос в его личные дела — попросту
невежливо.

2. Я прекрасно понимаю, что совать нос в его личные дела попросту** [т.
е. бесцеремонно] **— невежливо.**

Comment: А корректно такое словосочетание — совать нос попросту? В какой ситуации так можно сказать?

Comment: @Sharon это явный плеоназм, но, думаю, он возможен в имитации разговорной речи.